# Where should my AS3 hitTest go?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, methods, scope, hittest

I'm making a game in AS3.

My document class has two child classes:

- PhysObject
- Ground

I want to perform a hitTest every frame between PhysObject and Ground but I don't know where to put it.

I know it's always best to have keep the document class as small as possible so I want to avoid putting the hitTest method there.

Should I have the child classes communicating directly with each other? Or should I use a separate 'utility' class to do it?

I'm also not sure how to do either of these options; I only know how to perform hitTests in the parent class.

[image]
Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might get a more satisfying answer on the gamedev stack exchange: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

you can assign this property to any one object. 
Here is a  link to the hitTest Object.
I think it will help you.

http://mnaresh.blogspot.in/2011/11/simple-puzzle-game-using-hittestobject.html

Comment: Sorry, I don't think you've understood my question fully. My question is, where should the hitTest check be between class A and class B? Should it be on one of those classes? Or should it be on the document class? Or a new class to handle the hittests? I want to know which is most efficient/best convention.

Answer (score 0):

I generally put collision tests in whichever class collects all of the objects involved. Most full-featured games will not have the world simulation handled directly by their document class. After all, you also need menus or scoring screens or credits which you usually don't want to be physically simulated. I'd structure things something like:

- Document

  - PlayScreen (hitTest goes here, in an update function called by Document every frame)

    - PhysObjects
    - Ground
  - OtherScreen